# npm WARN: cannot run in wd ghost@0.7.4 npm install semver

Tags: node.js, npm, ghost-blog

I have updated node to v4.2.4 with npm v2.5.0 in ubuntu 14.04 server. When i trying to npm install to ghost blogging warning message displayed and stopped installation. This bug occurred in my Digital Ocean server.

The warning message is

> npm WARN cannot run in wd ghost@0.7.4 npm install semver && node -e "require('./core/server/utils/startup-check.js').nodeVersion()" (wd=/var/www/html/ghost)
>
> sqlite3@3.1.1 install /var/www/html/ghost/node_modules/sqlite3
>
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

I have tried with

> GHOST_NODE_VERSION_CHECK=false && sudo npm install --production

according to [this](http://support.ghost.org/supported-node-versions/), But not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What was the exact error message? Node v4.2.4 should work even on version 0.7.4 though they just release 0.7.5 if you want to upgrade.

Comment: @JTWebMan this bug occurred in digital ocean server, i have tried with local machine it works fine. Any solution to recover this issue?

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If you have found the solution, please explain how to do that below this question. I've searched a long time with no solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had issue with Digitalocean's small intense and swap space with large npm installs. You might need to follow the following instructions on increasing swap space as well as how often it is used.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: My droplet 512MB with 20GB. Is it possible to add ghost, LAMP and some custom small demo applicaitons with this swap or Have to increase the droplet?

Comment: You should be fine as long as the mysql databases are not to big.

Comment: Great.. This answer solves my problem.. Added a swap space.

Comment: Wonderful! This answer solves my problem too, thank you!